# How to delete in an array all element with more than 15 characters

Tags: php

I want to delete in an array (it's a very big array) all element with more than 15 characters. What is the best way (in performance) to do this?

Comment: add sample data of your array

Comment: What about performance between array_filter and simple foreach with unset?

Comment: @user3154581 you can measure yourself : ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a callback function:

```
$new = array_filter($array, function($elem) {
    return strlen($elem) <= 15;
});
```

This is also possible with a normal `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value) > 15) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val)
{
    if(strlen($val) > 15)
    {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}

array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to this problem through algorithmic aspect you definitly have to go through array and check size of characters in array. If size is bigger than 15 you have to delete the element. Minimal complexity is O(n) = n on unsorted array. You should give us some code and language you are working in.

Comment: Language is PHP, check the tag.

Comment: Well you could state that explicitly. Code above would do

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with:

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($array, function($item){

  return strlen($item) < 15;

});
```

Comment: You probably didn't see it, but I posted a [very similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20955968/1438393) before :)

Comment: Oh sorry, we were writing in the same moment!

Answer (score 0):

DEMO LIVE: https://eval.in/86391

I have done it for 2D array.

```
<?php
$arr = array(0=>array(0=>"1111111111","1"=>"22222222222222222"),array(0=>"111111111111111111",1=>"14554545454"));
echo "BEFORE";
print_r($arr);
for($j =0; $j < count($arr);$j++){
 foreach($arr[$j] as $k => $v){
     if( strlen($arr[$j][$k]) > 15){
       unset($arr[$j][$k]);
     }
 }
}

echo "AFTER";
print_r($arr);
```

**For 1D array:**

```
$arr2 = array(0=>"1111111111","1"=>"22222222222222222");
echo "BEFORE";
print_r($arr2);
 foreach($arr2 as $k => $v){
     if( strlen($arr2[$k]) > 15){
       unset($arr2[$k]);
     }

}

echo "AFTER";
print_r($arr2);
```